# Strange Behaviour of WinRT Popup

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have a Popup in a DataTemplate of a GridView.
The DataTemplate has 2 buttons which opens up this Popup. This works perfectly well. But I see some erratic behaviour when the GridView is scrolled.

**Popup opened**
[image: Works perfectly well!]

**When GridView is scrolled the popup stays on the page**
[image: Strange behaviour!]

**XAML Code for the GridView ItemTemplate**

```xaml
<DataTemplate x:Key="BrandItemTemplate">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Height="150" Background="White">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="125"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PagesPopup" IsOpen="{Binding IsPagesPopupOpen}">
                        <Grid Width="180" Height="150" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PopupList}"  Padding="8" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionMode="None">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ListView>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/closeIcon.png"  Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8">
                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                        <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="CloseIconTapped" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill"  AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Border Visibility="{Binding IsNew,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="25" Margin="5" Background="DarkGreen" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Text="NEW" FontSize="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="25">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="12" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0 0 0" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0 -12 05 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/pagesIcon.png" Height="30">
                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" CommandParameter="PagesIcon"/>
                                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/refIcon.png" Height="30" Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" CommandParameter="ReferencesIcon"/>
                                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected behavior. `PopUp` intentionally has a highest z-index to display over all other elements. An easy fix, would be to get rid of the `PopUp` all together, and move `{Binding IsPagesPopupOpen}` down to the `Grid` inside it and use it on that Grid's `Visibility` with a Visibility Converter instead. Except it would need to be moved to the bottom so it would display above the contents.

To Explain better. Instead of how you have it, do this;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BrandItemTemplate">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Height="150" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="125"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>        

   <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill"  AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   <Border Visibility="{Binding IsNew,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="25" Margin="5" Background="DarkGreen" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <TextBlock Text="NEW" FontSize="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
   </Border>
     <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="25">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="12" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0 0 0" FontWeight="Medium"/>
      <StackPanel Margin="0 -12 05 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/pagesIcon.png" Height="30">
          <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
              <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" CommandParameter="PagesIcon"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
          </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
        <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/refIcon.png" Height="30" Margin="10 0 0 0">
          <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
              <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" CommandParameter="ReferencesIcon"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
          </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <!-- We move it down here to ensure it appears over everything and without having to set a fixed z-index, and add your visibility converter -->
    <Grid Width="180" Height="150" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          Visibility="{Binding IsPagesPopupOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">

      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PopupList}"  Padding="8" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Medium"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
          </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      </ListView>
      <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/closeIcon.png"  Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="CloseIconTapped" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
          </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      </Image>

    </Grid>

  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Excellent Solution! Appreciated!